# Copy-on-modify behaviour in R

Tags: r

Hadley Wickham's book 'Advanced R' mentions that R uses copy-on-modify behaviour. That is if you run

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = x
tracemem(x)
y[[1]] = 7
```

it will return `tracemem[object_address -> copy_address]`: as expected but I struggle to understand why `tracemem()` does not print anything in the console when I run

```
z = x
z = z+4 #no reaction from tracemem()
z1 = x
z1 = c(x,4) #still no reaction from tracemem()
```

As far as I understand `tracemem()` should inform you when R copies the object on which it is called but doesn't here. Why is that?

Comment: What do you think should be copied?

Comment: I expected x to be copied when running z = z+4 and also when running z1 = c(x,4)

Answer (score 2):

Use `address` from the pryr package to investigate how addresses change.

```
library(pryr)

x <- c(1, 2, 3)
address(x)
## [1] "0xdaf25a8"

z = x
address(z)
## [1] "0xdaf25a8"
z = z+4
address(z)
## [1] "0xdaeece8"

z1 = x
address(z1)
## [1] "0xdaf25a8"
z1 = c(x,4)
address(z1)
## [1] "0xdaeee78"
```

Comment: this is certainly helpful but doesn't really answer the question? (Or at least, not in a way I could understand ...)

Comment: `tracemem` is an optional feature which only works if it was compiled in.  See `?tracemem` .  Using `address` we can see whether the address stayed the same or not  which is presumbly sufficient.

Comment: I guess my question would be: running `z=z+4` shows that `z` is now in a new location (when it previously pointed to the same address as `x`). Why does `tracemem()` not report this change, which seems to correspond to a copying event? Perhaps the copy is made when `z+4` is formed?

Comment: Presumably it's not smart enough to know that it could have reused `z`.  If you give it a bit of help it will reuse the address: `z[] <- z + 4`

Comment: Does the logic in my answer seem correct?

Comment: To really know one would have to examine the source of R but it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to hazard a guess.
When you run `y[[1]] = 7`, no memory has to be allocated/copied to evaluate the expression `7` before the assignment to `y`. (I feel like `y[[1]]` is a red herring here, I'd expect the same behaviour with `y = 7`.)

In contrast, when the right-hand side of the expression requires some computation/memory allocation, that allocation is done **before** the assignment, so the memory corresponding to the symbol doesn't have be copied. Specifically what happens in order is:

- evaluate `z+4`: we need to allocate memory to store the result
- assign the result to `z` (we don't need to copy the memory from `x`, because we are simply re-assigning the symbol `z` to a new memory location, i.e. the one that was allocated in the previous step)

The same logic would apply to your third example.

R doesn't have an easy way to express "add 4 to `z` **in place**, i.e. overwriting the original value", like `z += 4`; if it did, then this would presumably trigger the copy-on-modify behaviour.

I don't have memory profiling enabled, but I would predict that `x <- c(1,2); z <- x; z[2] <- z[2] + 4` **would** trigger a message from `tracemem()` (because the entire `x` object would be have to copied even though only the second element of `z` was changed).

We should be able to confirm this with the [`profmem` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profmem/vignettes/profmem.html), but it doesn't work as well as I thought, possibly (?) because these operations use **primitive** functions that don't get recorded properly (or because I messed up somehow?), so it's hard to see what allocations go with what operations ...

```r
p <- profmem({ x <- integer(1); z <- x; z <- `+`(z,2) })
> p
Rprofmem memory profiling of:
{
    x <- integer(1)
    z <- x
    z <- z + 2
}

Memory allocations:
Number of 'new page' entries not displayed: 2
       what bytes      calls
2     alloc   528 <internal>
3     alloc  1648 <internal>
4     alloc  1648 <internal>
5     alloc  1072 <internal>
6     alloc   256 <internal>
7     alloc   456 <internal>
8     alloc   216 <internal>
10    alloc   256 <internal>
total        6080
```